# How to split data in one cell to multiple rows and columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to **split the data** from cell to cell. I have a google sheet and in Column "I" I have technical information about products like this:

[image]

So I'd like to split it as shown in the image. What can I do? or Can you give me directions about which function or formule I need to read to solve this kind of question. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: You mean you need to split on newline characters?

Comment: If you want to split any data, you can split for chr(10) and spaces to trim it

Comment: Where is the cell reference? Your picture is impossible to understand

Comment: @JvdV for example if this information in column "I" so I need to split it like that to column J K L M N O P Q R S each red line

Comment: Then try `=INDEX(IF(I1:I="","",SPLIT(A1:A,CHAR(10))))` in `J1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you may need two splits: one to split rows in a cell, and the other to split records in two parts (description, value). To do this we can combine these functions:

- `JOIN` to get all values in a column as one chunk;
- `SPLIT` to separate values;
- `TRANSPOSE` to organise splitted rows vertically;
- `ARRAYFORMULA` to apply `SPLIT` as an array function.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(CHAR(10), I:I), CHAR(10)))," "))
```

Notes:

- `JOIN(CHAR(10),I:I)` - concatenate the data in the `I` column into one data block;
- `SPLIT(..., CHAR(10))` - split data by `Char(10)`;
- `TRANSPOSE(...)` - arrange splitted rows vertically;
- `SPLIT(..., " ")` - split by spaces, note that there's a parameter `remove_empty_text` which by default is true, i.e. treat consecutive delimiters as one, what suits your case;
- `ARRAYFORMULA` - make splitting to work as an array-formula.

Example:

[image: visual example]